# Asynchronous I/O reading from a file

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I've gotten ideas for multiple projects recently that all involve reading IP addresses from a file. Since they are all supposed to be able to handle a large amount of hosts, I've attempted to implement multi-threading or creating a pool of sockets and select()-ing from them in order to achieve some form of concurrency for better performance. On multiple occasions, reading from the file seems to be the bottleneck in enhancing performance. The way I understand it, reading from a file with fgets or similar is a synchronous, blocking operation. So even if I successfully implemented a client that connects to multiple hosts asynchronously, the operation would still be synchronous because I can only read one address at a time from a file.

```
    /* partially pseudo code */

/* getaddrinfo() stuff here */

while(fgets(ip, sizeof(ip), file) {
FD_ZERO(&readfds);
/* create n sockets here in a for loop */
for (i = 0; i < socket_num; i++) {
    if (newfd > fd[i]) newfd = fd[i];
    FD_SET(fd[i], &readfds);
}

/* here's where I think I should connect n sockets to n addresses from file
 * but I'm only getting one IP at a time from file, so I'm not sure how to connect to 
 * n addresses at once with fgets
 */

for (j = 0; j < socket_num; j++) {
        if ((connect(socket, ai->ai_addr, ai->ai_addrlen)) == -1)
        // error
        else { 
            freeaddrinfo(ai);       
        FD_SET(socket, &master);
            fdmax = socket;
            if (select(socket+1, &master, NULL, NULL, &tv) == -1);
        // error        
            if ((recvd = read(socket, banner, RECVD)) <= 0)
        // error
            if (FD_ISSET(socket, &master))
        // print success
        }
    /* clear sets and close sockets and stuff */
}
```

I've pointed out my issues with comments, but just to clarify: I'm not sure how to perform asynchronous I/O operations on multiple target servers read from a file, since reading entries from file seems to be strictly synchronous. I've run into similar isssues with multithreading, with a marginally better degree of success.

```
    void *function_passed_to_pthread_create(void *opts) 
    { 
        while(fgets(ip_addr, sizeof(ip_addr), opts->file) {
            /* speak to ip_addr and get response */
    }
}

main()
{
    /* necessary stuff */
    for (i = 0; i < thread_num; i++) {
        pthread_create(&tasks, NULL, above_function, opts)
    }
    for (j = 0; j < thread_num; j++)
        /* join threads */
    return 0;
}
```

This seems to work, but since multiple threads are all processing the same file the results aren't always accurate. I imagine it's because multiple threads may process the same address from file at the same time.

I've considered loading all the entries from a file into an array/into memory, but if the file was particularly large I imagine that could cause memory issues. On top of that, I'm not sure it that even makes sense to do anyway.

As a final note; if the file I'm reading from happens to be a particularly large file with a huge amount of IPs then I do not believe either solution scales well. Anything is possible with C though, so I imagine there is some way to achieve what I'm hoping to.

To sum this post up; I'd like to find a way to improve a client-side applications performance using asynchronous I/O or multi-threading when reading entries from a file.

Comment: I feel your pain, but there are many ways to read a file. The fastest approach, I'm aware of, involves reading a file sequentially with the native API functions (ie, ReadFile). Then you can spin off processing to different threads, etc.

Comment: This is useless to read a file with more than one thread read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10397184/7076153). You should have a manager who read the file and give to each thread a line of the file.

Comment: On a typical Linux system, the hard limit for maximum number of open descriptors (files and sockets) is typically 65536. (The soft limit, i.e. the default, is typically much lower, something like 1024.) Even if you assume extremely long host names and service names used (for the connections, instead of port numbers), you'll still need typically less than 100 characters per client. 65536×100 is only about 6.5 megabytes. Reading and tokenizing that (to host and port string pairs) is only going to take a fraction of a second. **It is insignificant.**

Comment: Let's say you only need the IPv6 (or IPv4) addresses. A `struct sockaddr_storage` is typically 128 bytes. So, if you read each host and port pair from the file, and use a thread pool to resolve them to connectable sockets using `getnameinfo()` (but close each connection immediately, for actual connecting later), you'll need about 144 bytes per client. Even a million clients is just 144 megabytes then; just 24 megabytes if you limit to IPv4. Unless you store the host names in numeric format, the name resolution is going to take the most time by far!

Comment: If you decide to store the host names in a numeric format, then you could just switch to a binary format; one file for `struct sockaddr_in`s, and another for `struct sockaddr_in6`s. You can read them lightning-fast, and write separate utilities to convert them to/from text files, with optional name resolution. So, overall, I just don't understand where you perceive a problem; I see none here. (I do work with large datasets myself, so I am not assuming any size limits in my logic here.)

Comment: @user3408678, how big is this file? Cannot you read it once, keep it in a data structure in a server process. This way you eliminate the I/O bottleneck and a thread pool in the server can be assigned with the task of giving the data to the incoming requests from clients... let me know if I am missing something here..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several people have hinted at a good solution to this in their comments, but it's probably worth spelling it out in more detail.  The *full* solution has quite a lot of details and is pretty complicated code, so I'm going to use pseudocode to explain what I'd recommend.

What you have here is really a variation on a classic producer/consumer problem:  You have a single thing producing data, and many things trying to consume that data.  In your case, it *must* be a "single thing" producing that data, because the lengths of each line of the source file are unknown:  You can't just jump forward 'n' bytes and somehow be at the next IP.  There can only be one actor at a time moving the read pointer toward the next unknown position of the `\n`, so you by definition have a single producer.

There are three general ways to attack this:

- ***Solution A*** involves having each thread pulling a little more out of a shared file buffer, and kicking off an asynchronous (nonblocking) read every time the last read completes.  There are a whole host of headaches getting this solution right, as it's very sensitive to timing differences between the filesystem and the work being performed:  If the file reads are slow, the workers will all stall waiting for the file.  If the workers are slow, the file reader will either stall or fill up memory waiting for them to consume the data.  This solution is likely the *absolute* fastest, but it's also incredibly difficult synchronization code to get right with about a zillion caveats.  Unless you're an expert in threading (or extremely clever abuse of `epoll_wait()`), you probably don't want to go this route.
- ***Solution B*** has a "master" thread, responsible for reading the file, and populating some kind of thread-safe queue with the data it reads, with one IP address (one string) per queue entry.  Each of the worker threads just consumes queue entries as fast as it can, querying the remote server and then requesting another queue entry.  This requires a little care to get right, but is generally a lot safer than *Solution A*, especially if you use somebody else's queue implementation.
- ***Solution C*** is pretty hacktastic, but you shouldn't dismiss it out-of-hand, depending on what you're doing.  This solution just involves using something like the Un*x `sed` command (see [Get a range of lines from a file given the start and end line numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237629/get-a-range-of-lines-from-a-file-given-the-start-and-end-line-numbers)) to slice your source file into a bunch of "chunky" source files in advance — say, twenty of them.  Then you just run twenty copies of a really simple single-thread program in parallel using `&`, each on a different "slice" of file.  Mushed together with a little shell script to automate it, this can be a "good enough" solution for a lot of needs.

---

Let's take a closer look at Solution B — a master thread with a thread-safe queue.  I'm going to cheat and assume you can construct a working queue implementation (if not, there are StackOverflow articles on implementing a thread-safe queue using pthreads: [pthread synchronized blocking queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577961/pthread-synchronized-blocking-queue)).

In pseudocode, this solution is then something like this:

```
main()
{
    /* Create a queue. */
    queue = create_queue();

    /* Kick off the master thread to read the file, and give it the queue. */
    master_thread = pthread_create(master, queue);

    /* Kick off a bunch of workers with access to the queue. */
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        worker_thread[i] = pthread_create(worker, queue);
    }

    /* Wait for everybody to finish. */
    pthread_join(master_thread);
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        pthread_join(worker_thread[i]);
    }
}

void master(queue q)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("ips.txt", "r");
    char buffer[BIGGER_THAN_ANY_IP];

    /* Inhale the file as fast as we can, and push each line we
       read onto the queue. */
    while (fgets(fp, buffer) != NULL) {
        char *next_ip = strdup(buffer);
        enqueue(q, next_ip);
    }

    /* Add some final messages in the queue to let the workers
       know that we're out of data.  There are *much* better ways
       of notifying them that we're "done", but in this case,
       pushing a bunch of NULLs equal to the number of threads is
       simple and probably good enough. */
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        enqueue(q, NULL);
    }
}

void worker(queue q)
{
    char *ip;

    /* Inhale messages off the queue as fast as we can until
       we get a "NULL", which means that it's time to stop.
       The call to dequeue() *must* block if there's nothing
       in the queue; the call should only return NULL if the
       queue actually had NULL pushed into it. */
    while ((ip = dequeue(q)) != NULL) {

        /* Insert code to actually do the work here. */
        connect_and_send_and_receive_to(ip);
    }
}
```

There are plenty of caveats and details in a real implementation (like: how do we implement the queue, ring buffers or a linked list? what if the text isn't all IPs? what if the char buffer isn't big enough? how many threads is enough? how do we deal with file or network errors? will malloc performance become a bottleneck? what if the queue gets too big? can we do better to overlap the network I/O?).

But, caveats and details aside, the pseudocode I presented above is a good enough starting point that you likely can expand it into a working solution.

Comment: Thank you this is perfect. This is definitely enough information for me to develop what I have.

Comment: You can also implement some kind of limit on how many concurrent connections are active at the same time. You can use semaphore/mutex in queue consumer code

Comment: Sorry, meant to award the bounty to this answer sooner.

Comment: No worries!  Just glad the answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

read IP's from a file, have worker threads, keep giving IP's to worker threads. let all socket communication happen in worker threads. Also if the IPv4 addresses are stored hex format instead of ascii, probably can read multiples of them in a single shot and it would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to read asynchronously you can use getch() from ncurses with delay set to 0. It is part of posix so you don't need any additional dependencies. Also you have unlocked_stdio.

On the other hand, I have to wonder why is fgets() a bottleneck. As long as you have data in file it should not block. And even if data is huge (like 1MB or 100k ip addresses) reading it into list at startup should take less than 1 second.

And why are you openining sockets_num connections to every ip in the list? You are having sockets_num multiplied by number of ip addresses at the same time. Since every socket is file on linux you will hit system issues when you try to open more than several thousand files (see ulimit -Sn). Can you confirm that issue is not in connect() in that case?